# how to reach vue object properties to show them on head

Tags: vue.js

I have a table where i show people's some properties. As these properties can be extended in the future, i need to show all the available properties in table head, and the related answers to those properties under table body

I can reach the people's properties with the syntax:
v-for='person in people' and  {{people.name}}
But i need to dynamically write 'Name' to table head.

Is there any option to reach to the object properties like name, age, salary, country, etc. ? 
ex: people={**name**:john, **surname**: black, **age**:35, **country**:german}

```
<table class="table table-filter">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Key</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Whatever</th>

                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Value</td>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>35</td>
                                <td>Green</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Value</td>
                                <td>Selin</td>
                                <td>23</td>
                                <td>Black</td>
                            </tr>                       
       </tbody>
```

Comment: Share live demo with your example and expected output in html table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with v-for directive you can cycle not only arrays, but objects also, just use second, nested v-for directive. Generic example:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th v-for="val, key in person[0]"> // with first object in array
      {{ key }} // show key - name for each column
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="person, idx in people" :key="idx"> // with whole array
    <td v-for="val, key in person"> // with each object in array
      {{ val }} // show value for each column
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thank you but it is not working! it shows the values, i need the key!

Comment: @user2486 It is the same for td elements. Or? What do you mean?

Comment: OP shared this sample data `people={name:john, surname: black, age:35, country:german}`

Comment: Edited again. This is what I use it for tables with unknown columns count.

Comment: @user2486 I am on smartphone. I cant write snippet. If you want, edit my answer.

Comment: I was saying this what you edited just to show value in td instead th

Comment: Wow, same pinch , me tooooo

Answer (score 0):

Accordibg to your sample data `people={name:john, surname: black, age:35, country:german}`

Key value in horizontal Table

```
 <table>
  <tr>
       <th v-for="(value, index) in people">
          {{ index }}
       </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td v-for="(value, index) in people">
          {{ value }}
       </td>
  </tr>
 <table>
```

Key value in vertical Table

```
 <table>
  <tr  v-for="(value, index) in people">
       <th>
          {{ index }}
       </th>
       <td>
          {{ value }}
       </td>
  </tr>
 <table>
```